Noob question since i just started doing proof-oriented math.
How would one prove that : $$∀(x,y) ∈ (0,1) (xy<1)$$
Assume $\exists xy \in (0,1)¬(xy<1)$ which is equivalent to $\exists xy¬(x,y \in (0,1) → xy<1) <-> \exists xy(0<x<1 \land 0<y<1 \land xy>= 1)$ which is basically a system of inequalities at this point.
How do I correctly depict in my proof that there are no such $x$ and $y$ that satisfy such system of linear inequalities.

Tried to solve a system of inequalities for 0<x<1 & 0<y<1 & xy>= 1

Write your attempt in your question otherwise it seems you just post like "do my homework for me please". See that you've already searched in your question. Otherwise you also get downvoted by the community which is not good for you to get an answer.

First, you should clarify what your premises and conclusions are. The theorem you are trying to prove is of the form $\forall x P(x)$. What are your givens in this case? You might want to consult some books on proof writing techniques; I recommend 'How to Prove It?' by Velleman, specifically the section on proofs involving quantifiers.

As for the specific question you are asking, I will provide a proof for a similar statement as a hint.
Theorem
$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} \land (a > b > 0) \Rightarrow a^2 > b^2 > 0$
Proof
We will do a direct proof, thus we need to assume the premises are true for some arbitrary $a$ and $b$.
Let a, b  be arbitrary real numbers, and assume $a > b > 0 $
Multiply both sides by $a$; since multiplication by positive real numbers maintains the inequality, we get:
$$a^2>a \cdot b>0 $$
Similarly, by multiplying both sides of $a > b$ by $b$, we get:
$$ b \cdot a>b^2>0$$
Since real numbers commute under multiplication, $a \cdot b = b\cdot a$. Writing the inequalities together we get:
$$a^2>a \cdot b>b^2>0$$
Finally
$$a^2>b^2>0$$
Which was the conclusion we wanted to achieve
